# Can someone please explain to me why if the angle between z-a and z-(conjugate a) is acute then we can conclude that Re((z-a)(conjugate z-a))>0?

Tags: roots, circles

Here in that question [Proof of Jensen's theorem on roots and circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3793007/proof-of-jensens-theorem-on-roots-and-circles)
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a do my homework for me site. Please edit your post to show an attempt.

Comment: Do you know about the relation between angles between vectors and the dot product? That's the key connection.

Comment: I just figured that that must be it (the relationship between angles and product) i'm trying to figure it out now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of the context of the linked problem, the general statement is:

> The angle between $z$ and $w$ is acute iff $\Re(z\bar w) > 0$.

Thinking of $z$ and $w$ as vectors in the plane, the angle between them is acute if the dot product between them is positive. This is because $z \cdot w = |z| |w| \cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the measure of the angle between $z$ and $w$. So $\cos\theta = \frac{z\cdot w}{|z||w|}$.  Therefore $\cos\theta > 0$ when $z \cdot w > 0$. The acute angles are the ones with positive cosine.

Now write $z = x_1 + i y_1$ and $w = x_2 + i y_2$. Then
$$
    z \cdot w = x_1x_2 + y_1 y_2
$$
while
$$
    z \bar w = (x_1 + iy_1)(x_2 - iy_2)
    = (x_1 x_2 + y_1 y_2) + i(x_2 y_1 - x_1y_2)
$$
So you see $z \cdot w = \Re(z\bar w)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, 
I appreciate it